# What does the BlueZ applet in Gnome do "behind the scenes"?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, gnome, bluez

I have this Apple wireless keyboard that I've successfully paired and gotten to work with my Ubuntu laptop (using a bluetooth dongle). The laptop is running 9.04 Jaunty and I used the nice little BlueZ applet that comes with Gnome to do the pairing.

What I'm actually trying to do though is to hook up the same keyboard, using the same dongle, to my HTPC that is running a stripped version of Jaunty (XBMC Live).

The problem is that the HTPC doesn't have Gnome and therefore no applet so I need to do the pairing manually on the command line.

What I've tried:

- `hcitool scan` -- Finds the keyboard okay
- `sudo hcitool cc <MAC>` -- Gives me a new prompt, just as if it succeeded pairing only I can't type anything

I also tried a lot of `hidd` solutions but since it works on the laptop that doesn't have `hidd` installed so I'm pretty sure that's not the way to go (plus the fact that `hidd` is deprecated in Ubuntu 9.04).

I also checked the `/etc/default/bluetooth` settings file on the laptop after the pairing and it doesn't contain anything new. So I guess I should be able to get it to pair without modifying it.

How can I check if it has succeeded in pairing? `hcitool dev` doesn't give anything on the laptop when the keyboard is paired.

Comment: I'd love to know how to make bluetooth pairing work in Ubuntu, I've never managed to get my PS3 to do it (while running Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Bluetooth myself, but there's a lot of information on the [BlueZ Wiki](http://wiki.bluez.org/wiki/HOWTO).  (Which is remarkably well hidden.  I couldn't find a single link from [www.bluez.org](http://www.bluez.org) to [wiki.bluez.org](http://wiki.bluez.org).)